# Cannot delete a dir as `root`, even after a `chattr -i`

Tags: ubuntu, root, rm, btrfs

I am trying to delete a directory, `foo`, and am totally out of things to try.

*Note: I know, I'm not supposed to delete LxD containers with `rm`, but I'd messed up this directory's contents earlier, and so, am okay using `rm` now.)*

Notice below, the parent of `foo` (i.e., the `containers` directory) has write permissions on it.

```
[root@box /var/lib/lxd]$ ls -l
drwx--x--x 1 root root    74 Dec 24 09:09 containers
    <snip>

[root@box /var/lib/lxd]$ cd containers/
[root@box /var/lib/lxd/containers]$ ls -l
    <snip>
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 231072 231072     0 Dec 24 09:13 foo

[root@box /var/lib/lxd/containers]$ ls -l foo
total 0

[root@box /var/lib/lxd/containers]$ lsattr 
    <snip>
---------------- ./foo

[root@box /var/lib/lxd/containers]$ lsattr -d foo
---------------- foo

[root@box /var/lib/lxd/containers]$ /bin/rm -rf foo
/bin/rm: cannot remove 'foo': Operation not permitted

[root@box /var/lib/lxd/containers]$ chattr -R -ia foo
[root@box /var/lib/lxd/containers]$ lsattr -d foo
---------------- foo

[root@box /var/lib/lxd/containers]$ /bin/rm -rf foo
/bin/rm: cannot remove 'foo': Operation not permitted

[root@box /var/lib/lxd/containers]$ ls -l
    <snip>
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 231072 231072     0 Dec 24 09:13 foo
```

Even a `chown -R root.root foo` does not help!

What's surprising is `lsattr` showing no additional attributes set on `foo`, both to begin with and subsequent to the `chattr` command. So, why `ls -l foo` was showing -- and is continuing to show -- the `+` next to `foo`'s listing?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 with ext4fs, with latest updates as of today.

**EDIT**: The filesystem is *btrfs*, and NOT ext4fs. This is an external USB hard-drive that I'm mounting on my host's `/var/lib/lxd`.

Comment: have you tried "chown root:root foo" and "chmod 555 foo" so that you can delete it? Seems to me that the folder is broken. :P Not that it helps much.

Comment: @cengbrecht I had tried `chown` earlier, but trying`chmod` this time didn't work either. By the way, see my EDIT above in a second.

Comment: what about ls -lah

Comment: what about fsck, have you checked the disk? (Just kinda throwing what I do to my servers at ya)

Comment: Nope. `btrfsck` reported no errors. `ls -lah` in the parent of `foo` reports 0 bytes for `foo`; inside of `foo`, it lists only `.` and `..` dirs, with a `+` addtional permission listed for `.`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bet is your directory is in fact a btrfs subvolume. I made a test. When I try to `rm` my test subvolume I get "Operation not permitted".

If I'm right, the following should work in your case:

```
sudo btrfs subvolume delete foo
```

I understand your directory is already empty, but in general case you may have to empty it beforehand.

---

#### Further explanation as requested:

> A subvolume is a part of filesystem with it’s own and independent file/directory hierarchy. Subvolumes can share file extents.

You can learn more from [btrfs wiki](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-subvolume). The main reasons one may want to create a subvolume instead of regular directory are:

- a subvolume can be mounted as it was a separate filesystem with its own options (compare: although you can mount a regular directory with bind mount, it has to exist within already mounted filesystem; btrfs subvolume may easily be mounted as the root filesystem `/`);
- one may create a subvolume snapshot which is a separate subvolume that initially shares all the file extents with the source subvolume.

#### Practical example:

My btrfs filesystem has the following internal structure (keep in mind this structure is something different than the directory structure seen by the system; mountpoints belong to the latter):

```
/                        # btrfs root filesystem mounted as /mnt/ssd/
  @                      # a subvolume I use as the root filesystem (mounted as /)
  @backups
    @-20161215-1-working # a snapshot of @ just in case
```

Let's suppose I want to mess with my system. As a precaution I create a snapshot first:

```
cd /mnt/ssd/@backups
sudo btrfs subvolume snapshot ../@ @-20161224-1-just_in_case
```

I do it from within my working system and it takes no time. It initially takes no diskspace as well. The additional space will be allocated later, when the corresponding files and directory trees begin to differ.

Next I can even break my system that resides inside the `@` subvolume. As long as the `@backups/@-20161224-1-just_in_case` subvolume is intact, I can replace `@` with this backup as if nothing happened. In the worst case I need to boot from a live distro to do that. But if my bootloader (GRUB2) still works, I can  edit its entry at the boottime and temporarily use `@backups/@-20161224-1-just_in_case` instead of `@` subvolume as my root filesystem. Then, from within the again working system I do:

```
cd /mnt/ssd/
sudo btrfs subvolume delete @  # I may have to empty it first
sudo btrfs subvolume snapshot @backups/20161224-1-just_in_case @
```

After that I reboot. The system is restored.

Comment: It worked, thanks A TON. But I'm shocked to learn how a btrfs subvolume (which is just a file-system by itself) is able to resist `root`'s `rm -f` and `chattr -i` commands. Where could I find more details about this, and other such shockers about btrfs? Would be glad if you could elaborate just a little bit on this in your answer, which I've already marked as final.

Comment: @Harry I have expanded my answer.